# Channel.fetch_message(id) doesnt return desired outcome

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to fetch the Instance of a specific Message by its id and wanted to use channel.fetch_message(id) but this returns a coroutine which hasnt got functions such as add_reaction(). What am i doing wrong?

This is the Method:

```
@commands.command()
async def reaction_on_message(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, message_id, emoji):
    message = channel.get_message(message_id)
    print(type(message))
    message.add_reaction(emoji)
    user = await self.bot.get_user_info(ctx.message.author.id)
    await user.send("Hello This Works!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use await before it. You can see that here in [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message)

```py
await channel.fetch_message(ID_HERE)
await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Comment: OMG well thats embarrassing that i forgot that xD Thanks solved the problem :)

Comment: No worries it happens, could you please mark it as solved.